# How do I start react-js development server in firefox not on brave even though my default browser in vscode is firefox too

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, firefox, web-deployment

Whenever I start my reactjs development environment using `npm start` it always opens in brave even though my default browser in vs code is set to firefox itself.

Comment: How is vscode related here if you are using terminal to run the server?

Comment: I'm running a terminal in vs code, hence the relevancy. Anything else ? or Is the question out of the scope of your knowledge?

Comment: Terminal in vscode is just a window that opens other terminals. It doesn't know vscode options